# What's the best way to access through attribute of many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have the following, each player has many games and each game has many players, a player can choose to either go or not go to a game.

```
Game
 has_many :shows
 has_many :players, :through => :shows

Player
 has_many :shows
 has_many :games, :through => :shows

Show Migration
  t.references :game
  t.references :player
  t.boolean :going, :default => false
```

All I want to do is set the going to true if a player decides to go to a game, what's the best way to make this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the id of the player (`player_id`) and the id of the particular game (`game_id`), you can do the following:

```
Show.where('player_id = ? and game_id = ?', player_id, game_id).first.update_attributes(:going => true)
```

This is more verbose, but possible too:

```
player = Player.find(player_id)
show = player.shows.find_by_game_id(game_id)
show.update_attributes(:going => true)
```

If you want to iterate over games you can do:

```
player = Player.find(id_of_player)

player.shows.each do |show|
  if show.game == ... # condition that decides whether player's going or not
    show.update_attributes(:going => true) 
  end
end
```